# Explicit (long long) conversion of arithmetic expression returns 0

Tags: c++, casting, long-long

When I multiply a `long long` value with a `double` value, I get a `double` value.

To convert it back to `long long`, I use `(long long)`.

But the output I get is `0`, when it should be `10`.

This is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long n = 100;
    printf("%lld",(long long)0.1*n);

    return 0;
}
```

Why is this? How can I fix this?

Comment: `(long long)0.1` That's actually `0`

Comment: Two things: First please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) Secondly, `(long long)0.1*n` is equal to `((long long)0.1)*n`

Answer (score 1):

You are casting 0.1 to `long long`. Which is 0. This will work:

```
(long long) (0.1 * ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

C-style casts have a higher operator precedence than arithmetic operators, like the multiplication operator.

So, in order to receive a non-zero result here, you'd have to put parentheses around the arithmetic expression to have it evaluated before the type conversion takes place.

For reference:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Quote from there (emphasis mine):

> **When parsing an expression, an operator** which is listed on some row of the table above with a precedence **will be bound tighter (as if by parentheses) to its arguments than any operator that is listed on a row further below it with a lower precedence.**